# Python remove element from linked list

Tags: python

Assume that there will be at least one element in the list when remov() is called, however, if there is only one element, then you will need to set head to None when that element is removed.

```
def remov(self): 
    current = self.head
    previous = current
    while current.get_next() != None:
        previous = current
        current = current.get_next()
    previous.set_next(None)
    return current.get_data()
```

I cannot return the right answer when there is only 1 element in the list.

example:

[image]

Comment: How do you know what you want to remove? I mean should `remov` be removing one element or clearing the whole list? Linked lists usually involve special cases for the first element. There is a good [tutorial](http://cslibrary.stanford.edu/103/) on linked lists. It's in c but thats really the best language to work with linked lists.

Comment: This program does not create images so your example output is not what it produces.

Comment: the program is different from the output, I just provide an clearer visual example from web, rather than I typing out the answer one by one, which is confusing.

Answer (score 0):

If you do a bit googling, you can find proper linked list implementations easily.
I extracted following code from [this tutorial](http://interactivepython.org/runestone/static/pythonds/BasicDS/ImplementinganUnorderedListLinkedLists.html)

```
def remove(self,item):
    current = self.head
    previous = None
    found = False
    while not found:
        if current.getData() == item:
            found = True
        else:
            previous = current
        current = current.getNext()

    if previous == None:
        self.head = current.getNext()
    else:
        previous.setNext(current.getNext())
```

Note: you have to be careful that, always last element's next node should be None

Comment: I tried, but the thing is, The answer provided show that it does not include 'item' in the function, so I have to iterate through the list and remove the last 'node' in the list, whether or not it is multiple nodes or just single nodes in the list.

Comment: I didn't understand what do you mean by `'item' in the function`. You mean, you want to have the tail element without iterating the until end?